# Save tag to a storage table how to convert it as a hashtable

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, azure-webapps

i'm trying to save app service tags to a storage table in this way:

```
$srcapp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "myrg" -Name "myapp"
$srcapp.Tags
```

$srcapp.Tags is this type:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Dictionary`2                             System.Object
```

i'm trying to convert it to a json to save it into table. In this way it works:

```
$jsonTag     = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $srcapp.Tags
```

when i try to get it from table with:

```
$Setting = Get-AzTableRow -Table $cloudTable -PartitionKey $PartKey -RowKey mykey
```

i got correctly the value as a string. When i convert it:

```
ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject   $Setting.Tags
```

i got an PSCustomObject but when i pass it to new-aztag i got error:

```
New-AzTag: Cannot bind parameter 'Tag'. Cannot convert value "@{xxx=xxx}" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable"."
```

there is way to convert it in an hashtable? I'm using powershell 5.1

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what `$Setting` looks like?

Comment: Hi @Paolo i get :

{
                   "creationDate": "xxx",
                   "division": "xxx",
                   "env": "xxx",
                   "project": "xxx",
                   "referent": "xxx",
                   "resourceType": "appxxxService",
                   "scope": "xxx"
                 }

Comment: Can you show the value of ```$jsonTag```, and also show how you're *storing* the value in the storage account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***To convert it as a*** `system.Collections.hashtable` ***from*** `system.Management.Automation.PsCustomObject`, ***you can use the below given PowerShell command.***

```
 ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject <inputdata>
```

***Note:*** Make sure that you've installed hash table modules. If not installed, install & import using below commands.

```
Install-Module -Name ConvertTo-Hashtable
Import-Module -Name ConvertTo-Hashtable
```

***I modified your script as below:***

```bash
$storageacc = "<StorageaccountName>"
$key = "xxxxxx=="
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageacc -StorageAccountKey $key
$jahnavitable = (Get-Azstoragetable -table "xxxtableName" -context $ctx).cloudtable
$jahnavirow = Get-Aztablerow -Table $jahnavitable
$jahnavirow.gettype()
$convertintohash = ConvertTo-Hashtable -InputObject $jahnavirow 
$convertintohash
New-Aztag -ResourceID "<ResourceID>" -Tag $convertintohash
```

I got an `PSCustomObject` and received the same error as shown here when I tried `New-Aztag` command initially.

[image]

So, I converted it to a hashtable using the `convertTo-Hashtable` command, and it is now `system.collections.Hashtable`.

[image]

And now I ran the `New-AzTag` command, which prompted me for the `ResourceID`.

[image]

Add the `resourceId` for which you want to add the tags and it will add successfully without any errors.

[image]

***Tags are added under the given resource in the portal:***

[image]